# how to do drag and drop from list to tree using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am new to React and I am trying to implement a drag and drop screen.

I found an example online using jQuery on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dLv7xk3t/). I copied the code here as a runnable demo since I can't just post links to jsFiddle without code examples.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do something similar to this in ReactJS?

```js
var exData = [{
  id: "loc1",
  parent: "#",
  text: "Location 1"
}, {
  id: "loc2",
  parent: "#",
  text: "Location 2"
}, {
  id: "italy-1",
  parent: "loc2",
  text: "Italy",
  icon: "fa fa-flag"
}, {
  id: "poland-1",
  parent: "loc2",
  text: "Poland",
  icon: "fa fa-flag"
}];

function makeTreeItem(el) {
  return $("<a>", {
    id: $(el).attr("id") + "_anchor",
    class: "jstree-anchor",
    href: "#"
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
      check_callback: true,
      data: exData
    },
    types: {
      root: {
        icon: "fa fa-globe-o"
      }
    },
    plugins: ["dnd", "types"]
  });
  $('#tagList li').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      var item = $("<div>", {
        id: "jstree-dnd",
        class: "jstree-default"
      });
      $("<i>", {
        class: "jstree-icon jstree-er"
      }).appendTo(item);
      item.append($(this).text());
      var idRoot = $(this).attr("id").slice(0, -2);
      var newId = idRoot + "-" + ($("#tree [id|='" + idRoot + "'][class*='jstree-node']").length + 1);
      return $.vakata.dnd.start(e, {
        jstree: true,
        obj: makeTreeItem(this),
        nodes: [{
          id: newId,
          text: $(this).text(),
          icon: "fa fa-flag-o"
        }]
      }, item);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#tagList ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tagList ul li {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .125em .2em;
  margin: 3px 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-header">
    Tags
  </div>
  <div id="tagList">
    <ul>
      <li data-tag="1" id="uk-1">United Kingdom</li>
      <li data-tag="2" id="france-1">France</li>
      <li data-tag="3" id="germany-1">Germany</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-header">
    Tree
  </div>
  <div id="tree">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "from list to tree". If you're looking for Drag/Drop, check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) on that.

Comment: Please go through below example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dLv7xk3t/   here they are able to add 'Tags' to any node of 'Tree' by drag and drop.  the same example i want to do using react js. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided is written in jQuery. Instead of trying to make jQuery UI's Draggable work in React, you should use React DnD. Here's an example that's fundamentally doing exactly the same thing.

http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/nesting/drop-targets